# I want to add up the corresponding prices

Tags: php

I want to reassemble the following array for each management_code, class_type.

```
$varArrayA = array(
    array(
        "manegement_code" => "1",
        "class_type" => array('A','B','C')
    ),
    array(
        "manegement_code" => "2",
        "class_type" => array('A','B','C')
    ),
    array(
        "manegement_code" => "3",
        "class_type" => array('A','B','C')
    )
);
$varArrayB = array(
    array(
        "manegement_code" => "1",
        "class_type" => "A",
        "price" => "200"
    ),
    array(
        "manegement_code" => "1",
        "class_type" => "B",
        "price" => "300"
    ),
    array(
        "manegement_code" => "1",
        "class_type" => "B",
        "price" => "300"                        
    ),
    array(
        "manegement_code" => "2",
        "class_type" => "B",
        "price" => "300"                        
    )
);
```

I want this result

```
$varArrayB = array(
    array(
        "manegement_code" => "1",
        "class_type" => "A",
        "price" => "200"
    ),
    array(
        "manegement_code" => "1",
        "class_type" => "B",
        "price" => "600"
    ),
    array(
        "manegement_code" => "2",
        "class_type" => "B",
        "price" => "300"
    )
);
```

I made it as follows.
I'm confused about incorporating conditions in class_type.
I would appreciate it if you could be help me.

```
foreach ($varArrayA as $i => $varValueA) {
    foreach ($varArrayB as $rowow ){
        if($rowow['manegement_code']==$varValueA['manegement_code']){
            $varArrayC[$i]['manegement_code'] = $rowow['manegement_code'];
            $varArrayC[$i]['class_type'] = $rowow['class_type'];
            $num = $num+$rowow['price'];
            $varArrayC[$i]['price'] = $num;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(($rowow['manegement_code']==$varValueA['manegement_code']) && ($rowow['class_type']==$varValueA['class_type'])){
        $varArrayC[$i]['manegement_code'] = $rowow['manegement_code'];
        $varArrayC[$i]['class_type'] = $rowow['class_type'];
        $num = $num+$rowow['price'];
        $varArrayC[$i]['price'] = $num;
    }
```

Just ask if the class_type is the same as well.